# Can't get boxes to react to size changes in css when put over video background

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create some boxes and for some reason cannot get them to move anywhere. I am newer to HTML/CSS and not sure what I am doing wrong. I am trying to make the background a video and figure out how to put my boxes on top. For some reason they appear only at the bottom but wont move with anything I put in CSS. Obviously I am not doing something right. I am trying to use a video as my background and would like to know also if I am going about this the right way even? To my understanding you cannot set a video as the background directly in CSS? Thanks for the help.

```css
/* font-family: 'Sedgwick Ave'; */
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Sedgwick+Ave&display=swap');

/* font-family: 'Bebas Neue' */
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Bebas+Neue&display=swap');

/* font-family: 'Nunito' */
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nunito:wght@200&display=swap');

#myVideo {
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
  }

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    max-width: 100%;

    /*     border:1px solid red; */
}

/*General Styles*/
html,body {
    font-size: 62.5%;
    /* background-image: url('/images/home-page-bg-black.jpg'); */
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.container {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}


nav {
    position: relative;
    height: 100vh;
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
  }

nav a{
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 2.2em;
    color: white;
    margin-top: 2%;
    font-family: 'Bebas Neue';
}

.boxes{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.box{
    background-color: red;
    position: relative;
    width: 10%;
    height: 80px;
    display: flex;
    align-content: center;
}

.box h4{
    text-align: top;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Portfolio</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/index.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div id=".container">
            <video autoplay muted loop poster id="myVideo">
                <source src="/images/Cyberpunk1-1 (2021_04_28 20_59_30 UTC).mp4" type="video/mp4">
            </video>
        <nav>
            <a href="#" id="nav-home">Home</a>
            <a href="#" id="nav-about">About</a>
            <a href="#" id="nav-project">Projects</a>
            <a href="#" id="nav-contact">Contact</a>
        </nav>
        <div class ="boxes">
            <div class="box"> <h4>TEXT HERE</h4></div>
            <div class="box"> <h4>TEXT HERE</h4></div>
            <div class="box"> <h4>TEXT HERE</h4></div>
            <div class="box"> <h4>TEXT HERE</h4></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: There is at least one fundamental syntax error here: id=".container." You're mixing id and class notation. Should be id="container" or class="container." The dot (".") selector notation is a CSS convention. It is not used in HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

**Changes:**

1. Correct class name to `<div class="container">`
2. In CSS for .boxes added

```
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
```

3. In CSS for .box added some internal spaces

```
padding: 10em;
```

```css
/* font-family: 'Sedgwick Ave'; */
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Sedgwick+Ave&display=swap');

/* font-family: 'Bebas Neue' */
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Bebas+Neue&display=swap');

/* font-family: 'Nunito' */
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nunito:wght@200&display=swap');

#myVideo {
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
  }

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    max-width: 100%;

    /*     border:1px solid red; */
}

/*General Styles*/
html,body {
    font-size: 62.5%;
    /* background-image: url('/images/home-page-bg-black.jpg'); */
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.container {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}


nav {
    position: relative;
    height: 100vh;
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
  }

nav a{
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 2.2em;
    color: white;
    margin-top: 2%;
    font-family: 'Bebas Neue';
}

.boxes{
    display: flex;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.box{
    background-color: red;
    position: relative;
    width: 10%;
    height: 80px;
    display: flex;
    align-content: center;
    padding: 10em;
}

.box h4{
    text-align: top;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Portfolio</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/index.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
            <video autoplay muted loop poster id="myVideo">
                <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            </video>
        <nav>
            <a href="#" id="nav-home">Home</a>
            <a href="#" id="nav-about">About</a>
            <a href="#" id="nav-project">Projects</a>
            <a href="#" id="nav-contact">Contact</a>
        </nav>
        <div class ="boxes">
            <div class="box"> <h4>TEXT HERE</h4></div>
            <div class="box"> <h4>TEXT HERE</h4></div>
            <div class="box"> <h4>TEXT HERE</h4></div>
            <div class="box"> <h4>TEXT HERE</h4></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```